# Adjectives starting with capital letters?

Tags: word-choice

Adjectives are written starting with capital letters in english?
Example: I don´t speak German... or german?
In Spanish we write "alemán" not Aleman because it's an adjective
Would you answer me please? thanks!

Comment: In that sentence, "German" is a noun, referring to the German language. It is capitalized because it is a proper noun -- it refers to a specific language which has a name.

Answer (score 4):

Proper adjectives (derived from proper nouns/names) are capitalised. Names of countries: German, French, Italian, etc, and of people, e.g. the Georgian period (reign of King George), Shakespearean, etc.

[What is a proper adjective?](http://blog.writeathome.com/index.php/2014/01/what-is-a-proper-adjective/)